# Cannot add records to a mysql database

Tags: mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I have defined a function to add rows to a MYSQL database. But it keeps giving an error saying-

```
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Here's my code

```
#add new records
def add_records():
    db = msq.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "abhi2004", database = "Movie_Sites")
    cur = db.cursor()
    count = int(input("Enter number of records to enter: "))
    for i in range(count):
        name = input("Enter name of movie: ")
        actors = input("Enter a comma separated list of actors: ")
        genre = input("Enter genre: ")
        ratings = float(input("Enter movie ratings: "))
        sql = "insert into movies(Movie,Actors,Genre,Ratings) values ({},{},{},{})".format(name,actors,genre,ratings)
        cur.execute(sql)
        db.commit()
    db.close()
    print("Records added")
```

How do I fix it? What's going wrong?

Comment: Show `sql` variable value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python)

Comment: Don't use string formatting to insert values into SQL queries, it won't automatically quote values that need to be quoted.  Use parameter substitution as described in the answers to the linked duplicate Q&A.

Comment: sql is a string